# Generic inherited methods

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a question about generic inherited methods.

Say for an example I have have a base manager class ListManager:

```
 public class ListManager<T>
{
    private List<T> m_list;

    public ListManager()
    {
        m_list = new List<T>();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { }
    }

    public void Add(T aType)
    {
    }

    public bool DeleteAt(int anIndex)
    {
    }

    public string[] ToStringArray()
    {
    }

    public List<string> ToStringList()
    {
    }

    public bool CheckIndex(int index)
    {
    }
}
```

And then an Animal manager class that inherits the List manager class above:

```
public class AnimalManager : ListManager<Animal>
{
    private List<Animal> AnimalList; //list

    public AnimalManager()
    {
        AnimalList = new List<Animal>();
    }

    public void Add(Animal animal)   // Exactly the same as base class method but with different method "content".
    {
        animal.Id = ++animalCounter; //increases the id by one.
        AnimalList.Add(animal);
    }

    public bool IsIndexValid(int index)
    {
        return ((index >= 0) && (index < AnimalList.Count));
    }

    public Animal GetElementAtPosition(int index)
    {
        if (IsIndexValid(index))
            return AnimalList[index];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public int ElementCount
    {
        get { return AnimalList.Count; }
    }

    public bool DeleteAt(int anIndex)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What do I do with the methods that inherit the ListManager? It needs the inherited methods but with different "content" inside the method.

I know that as long as a class inherits another class, they inherit everything their base class has, but what do I do if every management class handles different listboxes but has the exact same method head.

For example, every manager class has `Add`:

```
public void Add(T aType)
{
}
```

But my animal manager needs to add to animal list:

```
public void Add(Animal animal)
{
    AnimalList.Add(animal);
}
```

And my employee manager needs to add to employeelist :

```
public void Add(Employee employee)
{
    Employeelist.Add(employee);
}
```

They all have **exactly** the same method but with different "content".

Comment: Your title is  pretty poor. What _about_ "Generic inherited methods"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the base class methods virtual, and then override them in the derived class:

```
public class ListManager<T>
{
    private List<T> m_list;

    public ListManager()
    {
        m_list = new List<T>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(T aType)
    {
    }
}

public class AnimalManager : ListManager<Animal>
{
    private List<Animal> AnimalList; //list
    private int animalCounter; //variable

    public AnimalManager()
    {
        AnimalList = new List<Animal>();
    }

    public override void Add(Animal animal)
    {
        animal.Id = ++animalCounter; //increases the id by one.
        AnimalList.Add(animal);
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You may want to just extend the existing `List<T>`, if your base class isn't doing anything too special:

```
public class AnimalManager : List<Animal>
{
    private int animalCounter;

    public new void Add(Animal animal)
    {
        animal.Id = ++animalCounter;

        base.Add(animal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly do you have two lists? Use the base class's generic `m_list`, make it protected, and you won't have to reimplement anything. In derived classes (assuming they do something besides merely implementing a particular generic specialization), use `m_list` instead of their current `AnimalList` and so forth.

Comment: Like this in the base class: `List<T> m_list = new List<T>();` ?

Comment: @Kevin.A: Yes. Switch the `private` access modifier to `protected`.

Comment: But what do I do with the ones that required the list name of the subclass?

For example:  `AnimalList.Add(animal);` AnimalList was the name of the Animal manager list? How do I replace it with the list inherited from base?

Answer (score 1):

Your first class when complete does exactly what you want:

```
public class ListManager<T>
{
    private List<T> m_list;

    public ListManager()
    {
        m_list = new List<T>();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get {return m_list.Count; }
    }

    public void Add(T aType)
    {
        m_list.add (aType);
    }

    public bool DeleteAt(int anIndex)
    {
        m_list.DeleteAt (anIndex);
    }

    public string[] ToStringArray()
    {

    }

    public List<string> ToStringList()
    {

    }

    public bool CheckIndex(int index)
    {
    }

    }
}
```

Now you can use the class as follows:

```
ListManager <Person> plm = new ListManager <Person>();
plm.add (new Person ());
plm.Count ();
// and so on...
```

Same thing for Animal class.

In fact, if you do not require any functionality already in List, then `List<Animal>` and `List<Person>` will do.